# How to receive missed messages for 1 of N subscribers in ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, zeromq

I want to use an AMPQ service in Python applications, but haven't worked with ZeroMQ. So I want to know if this can be done:

- receiver1.py and receiver2.py subscribe to 'common_messages' from one host & port
- receiver2.py crashes
- sender sends a message
- receiver1.py successfully receives it
- receiver2.py is restarted
- receiver2.py receives the message that was sent while it was absent

Can this be done? Does ZeroMQ track what messages have been sent? If one subscribes after messages were sent, does ZMQ detect which old messages should to be received and which shouldn't be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a PUB-SUB connection (which it seems as if you are describing), then the quick answer is no. A Publishing [socket](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-socket) drops messages instead of queuing them.

Even if you change your socket types to PUSH and PULL, you will still have issues. Yes the PUSH socket will block on non-received messages but because you will have another client connected, the message will be sent and thus will not block if one of the clients drop. With PUSH-PULL types, you're not able to 'subscribe' to certain messages as you're able to with PUB-SUB connections.

You can implement some logic to do what you're describing. Checkout zmq's [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Designing-Reliability) (second bullet item) to see what they 'recommend' for a reliable connection. What is describing is essentially a method to keep track of which messages the client receives (incrementing id?) and a second connection that the client can then 'request that the missed messages be resent'.

---

The above section could also be implemented with a client to server 'heartbeat' that give the last message it received. The server checks this to make sure that the client isn't behind and re-publishes the messages if it is.

Answer (score 3):

`g19fanatic has already answered your question.`

Adding on to his answer:

ZeroMq provides super sockets. The key advantage of using this is that once you identify a communication pattern, it is very easy to use it. You do not have to worry about

1. Reading whole messages unlike normal sockets
2. You do not worry about the socket creation and details in the same way as normal sockets
3. Unlike normal sockets, zeromq socket can connect to multiple zeromq socket. It is very advantageous.

How ever, ZeroMq does not solve the issue of message persistence. (ZeroMQ stands for Zero Message Queue). Message Queues like AMQP implementations provide message queuing and guarantee of delivery. It stores message till it is delivered. To achieve this, it utilizes a more complicated protocol (AMQP). ZeroMQ provides messaging patterns only.

It leaves you to implement any protocol, persistence or other properties on top of it.

1. Some like to use AMQP infrastructure with ZeroMQ client.

   See [RabbitMq plugin to use ZeroMQ as client](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rmq-0mq/wiki).

   https://serverfault.com/questions/80679/how-to-pick-between-rabbitmq-and-zeromq-or-something-else
2. Other solution is to use Redis Pub/Sub : http://redis.io/topics/pubsub
3. Others combine it. https://github.com/pete0emerson/commander